# How to Run MPI-3.0 in shared memory mode like OpenMP

Tags: parallel-computing, fortran, numerics, mpi, compiling

I am parallelizing code to numerically solve a 5 Dimensional population balance model. Currently I have a very good MPICH2 parallelized code in FORTRAN but as we increase parameter values the arrays become too large to run in distributed memory mode.

I have access to a cluster with 15 nodes, where each node has two 8 core CPUs and 128GB of RAM. I want to write run a program with MPI-3.0 in shared memory mode so that each process does not generate its own copy of each array.

Before I can run anything on the cluster I have to test it on a desktop running Ubuntu. It is essentially one blade of the cluster in that it has two 8 core CPUs and 128 GBs of RAM. I will be writing and testing my code on it, so please gear your responses towards running programs on the Ubuntu computer.

I have read that there is a way to run MPI-3.0 in shared memory mode like OpenMP instead of its default distributed memory mode.

**Questions:**

1. How will I have to alter my code? Do I need to add in calls to other MPI functions like `MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE`?
2. How do I compile my code to run MPI-3.0 in shared memory mode? Will this be different if it is over several nodes?

Please give sample compilation scripts if you can. I also have only GNU compilers. The cluster I use does not support Intel compilers.

Comment: Yes you should be able to run MPI on a shared memory system. However, the way that it is actually programmed will be identical. Your code should be the same for both shared and distributed memory systems. How it is *run* is the only difference.

Comment: Furthermore, although I have not tested this, I believe that you should be able to run your code using the command `mpiexec -n 8 /path/to/application` to fake your computer into thinking it has 8 different nodes.

Comment: I have already run it on a shared memory system but I want the computing cores to share RAM, like in OpenMP. Some of my arrays are 6 GB so I need all the cores on each node to operate in shared memory mode.

Comment: Ah. Now I understand what you are asking, but I do not have the answer. If I were in your situation, I would simply reduce the problem size enough so that I could run MPI as I said above. Presumably this is all for debugging purposes anyway...

Comment: Well this is for a research project. So I need to scale the problem size up. I already have working code so the only thing preventing scale up is the memory needed. I have come across some documents and powerpoints from MPI conferences which suggest MPI-3.0 can share memory with new call funtions that have been added under the one-sided communication catagory. Functions like MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARE

Comment: www.eurompi2014.org/tutorials/hoefler-advanced-mpi-eurompi14.pdf                                                                                                                                                                                                              http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/BLISRetreat2014/slides/hammond-blis-2014.pdf

Comment: You said that you have access to a cluster with 15 nodes, each with 128 GB of memory. So on your ubuntu system, run a small version of your problem to test your code/output. Then, when you're ready, run your full-size problem on the cluster. If you just want to re-write your code working on shared memory system, you're probably better off just using OpenMP.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll if you do not want to answer the question as posed - meaning using MPI-3 shared memory and not OpenMP - then don't bother responding. It's counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this link on Stack Overflow. I swear I looked for questions like  mine for forever but it seems the best way to search a question on stack overflow is to start to make a question and it will suggest similar posts.

Anyway here is the link which does in fact say that you can run MPI3.0+ in shared memory mode like openmp. There are other sources I found which also suggest and some that state you can but do not explain how or give resources to figure it out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797298/mpi-fortran-code-how-to-share-data-on-node-via-openmp

After following the advice given here in this link I ran into issues with putting USE 'mpi_f08' at the top of my code. I am using gfortran-4.8 which apparently does not currently have enough FORTRAN2008 support to USE mpi_f08. There person in this link probably was using the intel fortran 2008 compiler. You can use USE mpi which covers up to Fortran2003 pretty well. However I do not think that Fortran 2003 has the Type() functions which are needed to use the Remote Memory Access functions, such as MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED, so you cannot use them without FORTRAN2008. But I really do not have enough resources to definitely say that for a fact but what I have found does suggest that.

Comment: You can use MPI_Win_allocate_shared with all three of the Fortran interfaces. Furthermore, you can write your own with Fortran 2003 ISO_C_BINDING and the C interface.

Comment: Please tell me why one needs Type() to use RMA from Fortran? I know of no such limitation. RMA has been used with F77 for many years.